# Java - how to iterate / traverse nested list of objects?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, iterator, nested-loops

I'd like to iterate over a nested list of objects. reservedOrder is a list of objects containing a list of PlannedOrder.

```
public class PlannedOrder {
      private Object name;
      private Object price;
      private Object quantity;      
}

final List<Object> reservedOrders = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (final Iterator iterator = AllOrdersList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
    if(condition){
      final OrderModel orderModel = (OrderModel) iterator.next();   
      final List<PlannedOrder> plannedOrders = new ArrayList<PlannedOrder>();
      final PlannedOrder singleOrder = new PlannedReservationOrder();
      singleOrder.setName(orderModel.getName());
      singleOrder.setPrice(orderModel.getPrice());
      singleOrder.setQuantity(orderModel.getQuantity());
      reservedOrders.addAll(plannedOrders);
      }
    }
```

Can someone explain why java.lang.ClassCastException is thrown here in this nested loop? How can I access each object in the inner list with for-each / iterator?

```
for (final Object order : reservedOrders)
    {
     final List<PlannedOrder> singleOrder = (List<PlannedOrder>) order;
        for (final PlannedOrder plannedReservationOrder : singleOrder)
            {
              // java.lang.ClassCastException is thrown here $PlannedOrder cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
reservedOrders.addAll(plannedOrders);
```

It seems that you're expecting the `plannedOrders` list itself to be added to the `reservedOrders` list.  But that's not what this does.  This adds each element IN `plannedOrders` to the `reservedOrders` list.  I think what you want instead is:

```
reservedOrders.add(plannedOrders);
```

This will cause the `plannedOrders` list to be added to the `reservedOrders` list, giving you the nested structure that you're expecting.

Why are you not properly defining the type of objects that are contained in `reservedOrders`?  If you did this, the compiler would then catch this error and so you wouldn't need to wait for a runtime error.  I think what you want is:

```
final List<List<PlannedOrder>> reservedOrders = new ArrayList<>();
```